# Cache the entire workspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, caching

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, if not, please direct me to the right pleace.

At work, we are using Eclipse inside of our remote Citrix machines. Because of this, the workspace is located on a network drive. When doing something for the first time after launch, for example right clicking a project, Eclipse always freezes for a couple of seconds. I think this is because of the delay from the network drive, because it works normally each consecutive time.

Is there a way to cache the entire workspace into RAM at startup to avoid this issue?

Comment: Is switching to a workspace on a local drive (via _File > Switch Workspace_) and adding the projects via _Open Projects from File System..._ to that workspace (which keeps the projects in their original location and does not move or copy the projects) what you want?

Comment: @howlger I should add that the projects are completely remote (working with SAP), so I only know the location of the workspace which has to be on the network share

Comment: If your Eclipse is local, it should be possible to have a local workspace into which the remote projects are linked.

Comment: @howlger since we are using Citrix, we cannot have our workspace locally, it **has** to be on the network drive